# how to rename index.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.1.3 version

In this I have created one application and rename the index.php file to main.php file.

Now When I create any anchor using codeigniter function anchor() it create link with index.php can any one tell me how to properly rename this thing so that it works properly.
Renaming index.php to main.php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read `config.php` it clearly says

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/98816/#499087